# Differentiate $\sin^{-1} \sqrt {1-x^2} $ wrt $\cos^{-1} $ if $x\in (-1,0)$

Tags: derivatives

Differentiate $\sin^{-1} \sqrt {1-x^2} $ wrt $\cos^{-1} $ if $x\in (-1,0)$

Let $x=\cos y$

Then $f(x)= \sin^{-1} \sqrt{1-\cos^2y}=\sin^{-1} |\sin y| =\pm y$

And $g(x)=\cos^{-1} \cos y =y$

$$\frac{f’(x)}{g’(x)} = \pm 1$$

Since $\sin y$ can be both positive or negative if $\cos y \in (-1,0)$

Which is the right answer?

Comment: $\sin^{-1}|\sin y| \neq \pm y$ and similarly $\cos^{-1}\cos y \neq  y$. For example, take $y=4\pi$, does it satisfy your equation?

Comment: Okay, he should have mentioned that $y\in (\pi/2,\pi)$ when letting $x=\cos y$.

Comment: I want to just clear this point to @Aditya in general that $\sin^{-1}\sin x \ne x$ and similarlly for $\cos $, See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748193/find-the-value-of-sin-1-cos-2-cos-1-sin-2-tan-1-cot-4-cot/3749468#3749468).

Comment: @ABCD, then the substitution doesn't make any sense because in order to perform substitution, it must be bijective mapping. OP surely would have confused that $\cos^{-1}x=y\implies x=\cos y$ which is not correct.

Comment: @SarGe, yeah it seems so, that's why I provided a link for seeing how to deal with inverse functions. Irony is, the answer to the question which I have written there, is asked by him only!

Comment: @SarGe y can be $y\in (\pi/2, 3\pi /2)$ and $\sin^{-1} \sin y =3\pi/2-y$ doesn’t seem to work for the domain you picked

Comment: @Aditya, my mistake. It should be $\pi-y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real $x,\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge0$

Let $\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}=y,\implies y\ge0, x^2=\cos^2y$ and $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

As $x<0,\cos y=-x$

$y=\cos^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cos^{-1}x$

using [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1)

Comment: What will be the value of $f(x)$ though? You found $y$ but $f(x)=\pm y$

Comment: @Aditya, $$f(x)=y=\cos^{-1}(-x)=?$$

Comment: No I meant will it be $\cos^{-1} (-x)$ or $-\cos^{-1} (-x)$?

Comment: @Aditya, the first option

Comment: Yes, how do you determine that?

Comment: @Aditya, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Answer (score 1):

You can simply go for direct differentiation

$$\frac{d(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2})}{d(\cos^{-1}x)}\begin{align}&=\frac{\frac{d(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2})}{dx}}{\frac{d(\cos^{-1}x)}{dx}}\\ &=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot(-2x)}{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\\ &=\frac{x}{|x|}\\ &=-1\qquad(\because x<0\implies|x|=-x)    \end{align}$$